# Cannot push to GitHub repo even though invitation is already accepted

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I just changed my MacBook SSD from 128 to 512. Yes, previously I've backed up important folders like Code, Work, Documents, etc. Once the new SSD is installed, all of those important folders are copied back to my MacBook.

Then I load all local githubs repo into SourceTree. So far navigating branches works OK, so looks fine.

Unfortunately, I forgot to copy the `.ssh` folder, so cannot push to my office's private repo. I removed my old SSH key from GitHub setting, put a new one, then asked my coworker to remove myself from the repo and invite again. After the invitation is accepted, I still cannot push:

```
git -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/new-ui-2023:refs/heads/new-ui-2023 
Pushing to github.com:xxxxx/xxxxx_for_android.git
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pushing to github.com:xxxxx/xxxxx_for_android.git
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: OK solved: create the SSH config file and run ssh-agent: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent